# Can't get geo_point to work with Bonsai on Heroku

Tags: heroku, elasticsearch, tire, geo, bonsai-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a `geo_point` field on Heroku/Bonsai but it just doesn't want to work.

It works in local, but whenever I check the mapping for my index on Heroku/Bonsai it says my field is a string: `"coordinates":{"type":"string"}`

My mapping looks like this:

```
tire.mapping do
  ...
  indexes :coordinates, type: "geo_point", lat_lon: true
  ...
end
```

And my `to_indexed_json` like this:

```
def to_indexed_json
  {
    ...
    coordinates: map_marker.nil? ? nil : [map_marker.latitude, map_marker.longitude].join(','),
    ...
  }.to_json
end
```

In the console on Heroku I tried `MyModel.mapping` and `MyModel.index.mapping` and the first one correctly has `:coordinates=>{:type=>"geo_point", :lat_lon=>true}`.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the index and re-indexing? Tire creates the index with mapping defined in the model only when it does not exist. Also, isn't geo point defined as `{lat: X, lon: Y}` less error prone? (Array positions, easier access in scripts, ...)

Comment: @karmi yes I tried deleting the index and recreating it, I'll try defining it as two values to see if it helps. Also, is there a proper null/empty value for geo_points? nil, {}, [], "", etc.?

Comment: Alright, I tried defining like so `coordinates: map_marker.nil? ? nil : { lat: map_marker.latitude, lon: map_marker.longitude },`, but I get this error now: `ParsingException failed to find geo_point field [coordinates]`. Also the field is now mapped to `"coordinates":{"properties":{"lat":{"type":"double"},"lon":{"type":"double"}}}` on Heroku.

Comment: Hmm, this is all weird. Can you try isolating the geo feature into a different model, and double-checking you drop & re-create it? And post the full code and the output of `localhost:9200/<YOURINDEX>/_mapping`?

Comment: Followed up with a few questions of my own via Heroku support.

Comment: @karmi there you go https://gist.github.com/mbillard/0de318114c0188a48faa I created a new class 'MyModel' with a single indexed attribute. The behavior is different on Heroku than on my local machine.

Comment: @nick-zadrozny Can you verify the Bonsai end and possibly submit an answer for other folks who might this?

Comment: @karmi I have submitted a support ticket last week (monday) with Heroku and they told me that they sent the ticket to the Bonsai guys. I'll keep this updated as I get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got this to work.  Index name '**myindex**' type name '**myindextype**'

On the local machine

```
curl -XGET https://[LOCAL_ES_URL]/myindex/myindextype/_mapping
```

save the output to a .json file.  example: **typedefinition.json** (or hand build one)

```
{
  "myindextype":{
    "properties":{
      "dataone":{"type":"string"},
      "datatwo":{"type":"double"},
      "location":{"type":"geo_point"},
      "datathree":{"type":"long"},
      "datafour":{"type":"string"}
    }
  }
}
```

On heroku enter the command

```
heroku config
```

and get the BONSAI_URL.  Put it in the follwoing commands in place of [BONSAI_URL]. (https://asdfasdfdsf:asdfadf@asdfasdfasdf.us-east-1.bonsai.io/myindex)

```
curl -XDELETE https://[BONSAI_URL]/myindex
curl -XPOST https://[BONSAI_URL]/myindex
curl -XPUT -d@typedefinition.json https://[BONSAI_URL]/myindex/myindextype/_mapping 
curl -XGET https://[BONSAI_URL]/myindex/myindextype/_mapping
```

1. Deletes the indes if it exists.
2. Createds an empty index.
3. Uses the .json file as a definition for mapping.
4. Get the new mapping to make sure it worked.